# Craft 3 Controller - Redirect with errors

Tags: plugin-development, controller

I cant get this to work.

I'm doing a post to a controller action. From that action I'm doing a lot of validations, db insert, file uploads etc.

Coming from Laravel Im used to is doing like this: (*example with no real variables or methods. Just for visual presentation*)

```
if(!$something->success){
  return redirect("controller-url")->withErrors([$model->errors]);
}
// Next steps...
```

From what I can read in the docs Craft recommend posting to the same page to handle errors and pass the model down to the view, but then doing a page refresh will do the same again so I dont like that.

My Controller is like this :

**Index** (Renders index template)

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->renderTemplate("plugin/settings");
}
```

**Post**

```
public function actionPost()
{
  if(!$model->validate()){
    Craft::$app->getSession()->setError($message);
    return $this->redirect("url-to-index-action");
  }
}
```

So the setError() works fine but I want to the pass all the errors from the model to the index action after a redirect and then down to the twig template. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Yii2 there is no such a thing as "redirectWithErrors". Usually you have 2 scenarios

1. There are validation errors -> display the form again with those errors
2. Successful -> redirect

The first one doesn't require a redirect. You just return `null` in your controller and Yii2 will route the to the url specified via `GET`parameter.

So you can have a form like this.

```
<form method="post" action="myUrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mycontroller/save">
</form>
```

Yii2 will do the following

1. Route to your controller and hit the `save` action
2. When you redirect or return a valid object of type `yii\web\Response` or a string that can be converted into that it will return the `Response`
3. When you don't return something it will route the request a second time with your get param `myUrl`, that can be treated as you `routeWithErrors` function because you set the errors `Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->setRouteParams(['model' => $model])` and have then access to these parameters.

If you really dislike this, you could use `return Craft::runAction('controller/action', $parameters);` to run a controller action with certain values

**Edit** 
Usually you want to leave `action="myUrl"` blank and don't insert it. That way Yii2 will automatically reload the current route so you can dispaly your errors